# command line solution of “crontab: tmp/tmp.X: Operation not permitted”

Tags: mac-osx, cron, file-permissions, update

I have the following problem. But I only have ssh access to the Mac machine. So I not use any GUI solution. Is there a way to enable this in the command line? Thanks.

[OSX mojave: "crontab: tmp/tmp.X: Operation not permitted"](https://serverfault.com/questions/954586/osx-mojave-crontab-tmp-tmp-x-operation-not-permitted/954590)

Comment: If you have the same problem, the second answer on the post you linked is a cli solution.  The problem is a gui (terminal.app) problem in that question.  I think you need to explain more detail.

Comment: OK. I see. it works. But I don't understand why it works. When I access the machine, I already ssh once. But it is necessary to ssh to the same host a second time.?